# Python | How could I make a function that returns the no commons of two lists

Tags: python

I tried to write a code, a function more specifically, which takes two arguments, two lists of numbers and returns a list that has the items of both lists except the common ones. 
 **Here is my code :**

```
def nocommons(l1,l2):
for i in l1:
    if i in l2:
        l1.pop(l1.index(i))
        l2.pop(l2.index(i))

return l1 + l2

print nocommons([1,4,6],[1,4,5]) #I want this to return : [6,5]
```

First of all I would like you to correct my error, then I would be glad if you suggested me any better way of doing that. 

Thanks in advance !

Comment: what is your error ?

Comment: I have no idea, my function returns [4,6,4,5] ..

Comment: If we convert your list into sets there is a function for that: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/set#symmetric

Comment: Can you not use `set` for this? `set([1,4,6]) ^ set([1,4,5])`

Comment: stackoverflow is not an error correction service. The error message you are getting says exactly what the problem is. It requires minimal effort. Give it a try first

Comment: Your error stems from the common misshandling of iterating over a list while modifying it. Usually, it is best to simply avoid it all together, and only modify copies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a better way: Use sets, for which the exclusive or operator, `^` is defined:

```
def nocommons(l1,l2):
    return list(set(l1) ^ set(l2))
```

The outer `list` call is not strictly necessary, unless the returned object has to be a list, of course.

Comment: Wow ... Thanks .. That's the fastest way I could have ever imagine ..